# Kerberos CLIENT_NOT_FOUND while logon from WinXP to Ubuntu16.04 Samba Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, kerberos, samba, ubuntu-server

since Samba is meanwhile fully able to act as Active Directory replacement, I plan to setup it for a school network (using old XP and Win7 clients). I installed all my packages from the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS repos.

Setting up the server worked pretty well, but after joining the domain via WinXP, I cannot loggon: "username or domain not found".

**/var/log/auth.log**

```
Mar 26 14:41:39 server krb5kdc[967]: AS_REQ (7 etypes {23 -133 -128 3 1 24 -135}) 192.168.0.103: CLIENT_NOT_FOUND: chrglo@FSG for krbtgt/FSG@FSG, Client not found in Kerberos database
Mar 26 14:41:39 server krb5kdc[967]: DISPATCH: repeated (retransmitted?) request from 192.168.0.103, resending previous response
```

But the account chrglo exists within Kerberos:

```
fsgadmin@server:~$ kinit chrglo
Password for chrglo@FSG.LAN:
fsgadmin@server:~$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000

Default principal: chrglo@FSG.LAN
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
26.03.2018 14:43:42  27.03.2018 00:43:42  krbtgt/FSG.LAN@FSG.LAN
renew until 27.03.2018 14:43:39`
```

I tried several(!) google results dealing with various (but not identical) issues of that kind. But none of them helped.

Here's my Kerberos configuration:

**/etc/krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = FSG.LAN
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
    FSG.LAN = {
            kdc = server.fsg:88
            admin_server = server.fsg:749
            default_domain = FSG
    }

[domain_realm]
    .fsg.lan = FSG.LAN
    fsg.lan = FSG.LAN

[logging]
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/kadmin.log
    default = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/krb5lib.log
```

and my Samba configuration:

**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
[global]
    workgroup = FSG
    realm = FSG.LAN
    netbios name = SERVER
    server role = active directory domain controller
    dns forwarder = 192.168.0.254
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
```

Here's some screenshots from the XP client (btw both server and client running within a VirtualBox): the client was added to the domain and offers to logon using it, but stops after the (previously noticed) error message.

[Client joined the domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feZUI.png)

[Client at domain logon screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC4f4.png)

[Error after logon try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkvsq.png)

Has anyone an idea where I screwed up the configuration?

Glocke

/EDIT: for the sake of providing more information: DHCP is done via an external piece.

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.fsg

192.168.0.250   server.fsg server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/EDIT2: requested ipconfig / ifconfig:

[ipconfig /all on xp client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pTZk.png)

**on Server:**

```
fsgadmin@server:~$ ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 08:00:27:ef:bc:56  
      inet Adresse:192.168.0.250  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: fe80::a00:27ff:feef:bc56/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:154 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:82 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:18341 (18.3 KB)  TX-Bytes:11263 (11.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:650 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:650 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1 
      RX-Bytes:52072 (52.0 KB)  TX-Bytes:52072 (52.0 KB)
```

**Furthermore**: While the client joins the domain, some auth.log is happening on the server (I used the Samba builtin Administrator account information while joining):

```
Apr 10 16:11:54 server krb5kdc[1037]: AS_REQ (7 etypes {23 -133 -128 3 1 24 -135}) 192.168.0.235: CLIENT_NOT_FOUND: Administrator@fsg.lan for krbtgt/fsg.lan@fsg.lan, Client not found in Kerberos database
Apr 10 16:11:54 server krb5kdc[1037]: DISPATCH: repeated (retransmitted?) request from 192.168.0.235, resending previous response
Apr 10 16:11:54 server krb5kdc[1037]: AS_REQ (7 etypes {23 -133 -128 3 1 24 -135}) 192.168.0.235: CLIENT_NOT_FOUND: Administrator@fsg.lan for krbtgt/fsg.lan@fsg.lan, Client not found in Kerberos database
Apr 10 16:11:54 server krb5kdc[1037]: DISPATCH: repeated (retransmitted?) request from 192.168.0.235, resending previous response
Apr 10 16:11:54 server krb5kdc[1037]: AS_REQ (7 etypes {23 -133 -128 3 1 24 -135}) 192.168.0.235: CLIENT_NOT_FOUND: Administrator@fsg.lan for krbtgt/fsg.lan@fsg.lan, Client not found in Kerberos database
Apr 10 16:11:54 server krb5kdc[1037]: DISPATCH: repeated (retransmitted?) request from 192.168.0.235, resending previous response
Apr 10 16:11:54 server krb5kdc[1037]: AS_REQ (7 etypes {23 -133 -128 3 1 24 -135}) 192.168.0.235: CLIENT_NOT_FOUND: Administrator@fsg.lan for krbtgt/fsg.lan@fsg.lan, Client not found in Kerberos database
Apr 10 16:11:54 server krb5kdc[1037]: DISPATCH: repeated (retransmitted?) request from 192.168.0.235, resending previous response
```

Also, stuff is logged to samba/log.samba

```
[2018/04/10 16:13:45.999444,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:328(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018/04/10 16:13:46.002791,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:328(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate:   File "/usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate", line 621, in <module>
[2018/04/10 16:13:46.006441,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:328(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate:     get_credentials(lp)
[2018/04/10 16:13:46.006826,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:328(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate:   File "/usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate", line 125, in get_credentials
[2018/04/10 16:13:46.006930,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:328(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate:     raise e
[2018/04/10 16:13:46.007037,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:328(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: RuntimeError: kinit for SERVER$@FSG.LAN failed (Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm)
[2018/04/10 16:13:46.007099,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:328(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: 
[2018/04/10 16:13:46.021901,  0] ../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:294(dnsupdate_nameupdate_done)
  ../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:294: Failed DNS update - NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Comment: Let's see an ipconfig /all from the server and also from the XP client.

Comment: added as edit to original post (sry about the output's language, feel free to ask in case of difficulties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: samba provides its own kerberos admin server - no need to install it on my own :S